# Install android studio debian Unable to locate package lib32z1

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, debian, package

trying to install android studio on a debian 64 bits virtual machine, I got the famous error : Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool

I understood I am missing some packages so I tried : 
su
apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6

but I got

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lib32z1
E: Unable to locate package lib32ncurses5
E: Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32bz2-1.0'
E: Unable to locate package lib32stdc++6
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32stdc++6'

So it won't work, I have been looking all over the internet without success...
Thanks for your help guys !

Comment: I wish someone answered this post...

Answer (score 3):

It seems to not be present on some version of Ubuntu 64 bits, but the following should bring it:

**Add support for 32 bit packages:**

> sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

**add the specific 32 bits version of that requested package:**

> sudo apt-get install libbz2-1.0:i386

Also tried to install android studio today and found it strange that the people writing the Installation Guide for Android Studio do not mention this at the time of writting ;-(

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your package lists are incomplete or otherwise defective. I'd try running `sudo apt-get update` before retrying your install command.